# Check Joomla Login From Wordpress Blog

Tags: php, wordpress, integration, joomla1.5

We have a Joomla 1.5 site with a blog in a subfolder `/blog/`

We would like to have a login status at the top of each page. For consistency of navigation we want to show the joomla login status at the top of the wordpress blog.

eg.:

*Login | Register | Help*

or

*You are loged in as **stephen baugh** | Help*

The problem is that although the scipt blow correctly returns the login status, if I add it to a wordpress template the status is correctly returned and drawn to the screen, but then the page stops drawing. Anyone have any ideas how I stop the Joomla scripts making the Wordpress script stop.

```
<?php

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', '/Library/WebServer/testqueensberrycom');
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
//$mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterInitialise');
//$mainframe->route();
//$mainframe->authorize('');

$user =& JFactory::getUser();

if (($user->id) > 0){
   return 'You are signed in as: <a href="/editprofile/user.html">' . $user->username . '</a> | <a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=225">Help</a> | <a href="/index.php?option=com_user&task=logout&return=cGFydG5lci9wcm9jZXNzL3BhcnRuZXIuaHRtbA==">Sign out</a>';
} else {
   return '<a href="/index.php?option=com_user&view=login">Login</a> | Join | <a href="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=225">Help</a>';
}

?>
```

Comment: To be clear. This is a php script I am trying torun within the wordpress install. It is not the script itself that is the problem. It is that it seems to kill the wordpress session.

Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there are a lot of possibilities. Joomla has a lot of features like register globals emulation etc (many depend on if you're using legacy mode...) - which could easily clash with other scripts. It also makes lots of defines and fills a lot of global spots, which could also possibly clash with other scripts.

Things I could think of to try:

- Add `$mainframe->close();`
- Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` after the Joomla code has run to see what Wordpress is choking on